# How to get UTC timestamp in Python WITH ALL DIGITS

Tags: python, timestamp, powerbi, utc

I am using this in my Python Script

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```

in order to print timestamps every 5 seconds (and also power values). I want to later use the timestamps and power values to create graphs in Power BI. The problem is that sometimes the timestamp printed is like this (see error too)

```
DataFormat.Error: The provided input could not be analyzed as a DateTime value.
Details
    2019-6-16T20:58:5.488
```

The problem is that the seconds are `5.488` and not `05.488`

I have not found a solution in Power BI, so I thought maybe there is a way to actually print it like this in the Python script from the beginning

```
2019-6-16T20:58:05.488
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to set a format yourself.

try this:

```py
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Output:

> 2019-06-27T11:18:03.663386

Comment: wait, I'm a bit confused, as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), isoformat should give exactly this...

Comment: he wants it with milisecond accuracy, not microsecond

Comment: @Adam.Er8 you are right, it should give it like this. For some reason sometimes it is correct and sometimes I am missing the 0. I will test with your solution and hopefully it works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by just formatting the datetime string like so:

say your time is now

```
import datetime as dt

cur_time = dt.datetime.now()

print(print(str(cur_time).replace(' ','T')[:-3])
```

this produces:

```
2019-06-27T14:21:10.853
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of isoformat() use strptime()
`dt = datetime.datetime.strftime("21/11/06 16:30.1321", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M.%ffffff")`
In your case something like 
`dt = datetime.datatime.strptime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "%d/%m/%y %H:%M.%f")`

Here you have all about datatime codes for formating: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime